How do I install a python module for use in a Raycast command script?
On MacOS I'm using the Raycast application launcher which lets you write command scripts to be executed from the raycast menu or a shortcut key.
I wrote a short python script to send simple keyboard output using the pynput module. It worked as expected when I ran it manually from my command line but then I pasted it into a new Raycast command script:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Required parameters:
# @raycast.schemaVersion 1
# @raycast.title Text macro
# @raycast.mode compact

# Documentation:
# @raycast.description Write some text for me

from pynput.keyboard import Key
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as KeyboardController
import time

keyboard_controller = KeyboardController()

keyboard_controller.type("Hello world")

# script exits before all the keyboard output is sent so I had to put a sleep here
time.sleep(3)

When I execute the script from Raycast, it throws an error:
Reason: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/Projects/raycast-commands/aws-tags.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
Domain: scripts
Time: 13:56:07.272

Either I need to install pynput in a different way or I am not importing it correctly for the Raycast script.

I'm not familiar with MacOS and Raycast but it appears you have pynput installed globally on your machine but not installed in the Raycast environment. Would it be possible to use a virtual environment?

No unfortunately not. I've posted an answer with the fix I ended up using

I fixed this by running:
python3 -m pip install pynput


you mean you fixed it by a simple pip install haha! I hope you were not mad at yourself.
